# How to override jQuery promise callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I've created a convenience method that adds a default error handler for my ajax calls:

```
function myAjaxFunction(url, data) {

    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data

    }).fail(myErrorHandler);

}
```

So far, this works great, because now I don't have to specify the error handler function in 50 different places.

But sometimes I need to override the default error handler with a custom one. When I do this, however, it calls *both* error handlers:

```
myAjaxFunction("myurl", "mydata").fail(myCustomErrorHandler).then(doSomething);
```

How do I get it to override or remove the previous error handler from the chain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I get it to remove the previous error handler from the chain?

You cannot.

> or override it?

You could undo what it did (overriding its effects). However, you should better avoid adding the general handler at all - to do that, you will have to change your convenience method. I'd recommend a custom handler as an optional parameter:

```
function myAjaxFunction(url, data, customHandler) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data

    }).fail(customHandler || myErrorHandler);
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion with the optional parameter.

Comment: This is correct but unsatisfying. It means the user of this has to straddle the old callback-based and new Promises-based APIs.