# Provide a default 'fail' method for a jQuery deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I am writing a Javascript API client using jQuery. My top level request method looks like this:

```
function request(method, uri, params, proxies) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    data: method == 'GET' ? params : JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: api.root + uri,
    type: method,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    }
  }).done(function(body) {
    deferred.resolveWith(this, [body.data]);
  }).fail(function(xhr) {
    deferred.rejectWith(this, [xhr]);
  });

  return deferred.promise();
},
```

How can I have a default `fail` handler for my returned deferred? That is, if the deferred has no other handlers attached to it's `fail` condition, call a default handler.

I want to do this to have global exception handling in my application, except for the parts that have a specific handling (and will define their own `fail` handler on the deferred).

Comment: deferred objects don't work that way. Instead, have a global error handler and then disable global events for that ajax request.

Comment: Don't use the `$.Deferred` interface here. Just call the `then` method (or `pipe` in old jQuery versions) on the promise returned by `$.ajax()`!

Comment: There's a global [`ajaxError` event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/), and you can use [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) for default options.

Comment: `ajaxError` doesn't do it for me, because it fires for ALL requests, regardless of whether there is special handling or not. I understand that that is now standard deferred behaviour, but is there an easy way of achieving the same?

Comment: Either you want a default fail handler or a specific fail handler. There's no half-way house!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override jQuery promise callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18474535/1048572) (and many more [similar ones](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=default+handler+[promise]))

Answer (score 3):

So, the cleanest way to use jQuery ajax in an API as of 2016 is to return a promise.  But, you cannot determine whether a caller has attached an error handler or not to the promise.

So, what I'd suggest is that you just add a new argument to your function that tells the function to NOT apply the default error handling because the caller will take care of the error handling.  And, I'd suggest you avoid the promise anti-pattern by just using the existing promise `$.ajax()` already returns rather than creating your own deferred:

```
function request(method, uri, params, proxies, skipDefaultErrorHandling){
    // default error handling will be used if nothing is passed
    // for skipDefaultErrorHandling
    var p = $.ajax({
        data: method=='GET'?params:JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        url:  api.root + uri,
        type: method,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
    if (!skipDefaultErrorHandling) {
       // apply default error handling
       p = p.then(null, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           // put here whatever you want the default error handling to be
           // then return the rejection with the various error parameters available
           return $.Deferred().reject([jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown]);
       });
    }

    return p;
};
```

Then, the caller just decides whether to apply their own error handling or not:

```
request(...).then(function(data) {
    // success code here
});
```

---

Or, you can go with a non-promise `failHandler` callback that you pass in and your default error handling looks to see if that `failHandler` was passed in or not.  This is hybrid of promises and callbacks and is not something I would normally choose to architect, but since your question asks for something that promises do not support, this is one of achieving that:

```
function request(method, uri, params, proxies, failHandler){
    // default error handling will be used if nothing is passed
    // for skipDefaultErrorHandling
    var p = $.ajax({
        data: method=='GET'?params:JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        url:  api.root + uri,
        type: method,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
    // apply default error handling
    p = p.then(null, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       if (failHandler) {
           // call passed in error handling
           failHandler.apply(this, arguments);
       } else {
           // do your default error handling here
       }
       // then keep the promise rejected so the caller doesn't think it
       // succeeded when it actually failed
       return $.Deferred().reject([jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown]);
    });

    return p;
};
```