# How to create a Promise with default catch and then handlers

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, ecmascript-6, koa

I'm creating an API that is using koa and babel async/await

Every promise in my controllers function looks like this:

```
async function ... {
    await Promise ... 
       .then(data => response function)
       .catch(err => err function)
}
```

Each promise has the exact same response and error function.

Is there a way for me to automatically have each promise resolve with the same then/catch (like a default resolve function for the promise).

Then my code would look like this:

```
async function ... {
    await Promise ... 
}
```

and the promise would auto resolve/catch.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Default behavior if no other functions chained to a promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043102/default-behavior-if-no-other-functions-chained-to-a-promise/37043286#37043286)

Comment: WTH don't you use `try { return response(await promise) } catch (e) { err(e) }` if you're having async/await?

Comment: I use that in many cases, but in this case I'm not.

Comment: This looks like Koa misunderstanding to me. Instead, you'd tend to use a middleware function upstream that handles downstream success and failure, all in one place. Use middleware to factor out repetitive logic and keep your routes minimal, that's what it's for.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use composition:

```
class MyPromise {
    constructor(executor) {
       this.promise = new Promise(executor);
       this.promise = this.promise
                          .then(defaultOnFulfilled, defaultOnReject);
    }
    then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
       return this.promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
    }
    catch(onRejected) {
       return this.promise.catch(onRejected);
    }
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
new MyPromise((resolve, reject) => {... }).then(() => {
   // default actions have already run here
});
```

Comment: Sounds like `const applyDefaults = promise => promise.then(defaultOnFulfilled, defaultOnReject);` is much easier to write and use…

Comment: @Bergi right, but I understood from OP's question that they want to be able to do `new Promise(executor)` and have that apply to all chains with it.

Comment: I guess `function PromiseWithDefaults(executor) { return new Promise(executor).then(defaultOnFulfilled, defaultOnReject); }` would still do it - no need to "subclass" `Promise`

Comment: Is there a way to avoid calling `.then()` or `.catch()` altogether?

Comment: @asuna you don't actually have to call `then` and `catch`, you would just use `MyPromise` in favor of `Promise` everywhere and things will be handled automagically for oyu.

Comment: Ok so right now, the promises are actually being generated via the mongodb node driver. In this case, I should set `this.promise = executor` in the constructor instead of `this.promise = new Promise(executor)` right? And then `await new MyPromise(mongodbPromise)`.

How does this code work? I'm a bit confused how you can set "then" and "catch" in separate functions like that.